# Android ListView custom id

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make a `ListView` that when I click to some item get custom `ID` that I point to each element of `ExampleArray`. I know about the `OnItemClickListener`. But my problem is how to point the id to each element from `ExampleArray`. The `ExampleArray` I get from database. The `example1` in the database have `ID=32`, `example2` have `ID=50`.... what array to use and what adapter.

**PS:** I'm new in Android world.

```
ExampleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ExampleList);

String[] ExampleArray = {"example1","example2","example3"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,casovi);

ExampleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTag and getTag for this on the View that getView returns. Be aware that this tag is also used for recycling your views.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to your problem is simple. Use `CursorAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead.

Ref for this are:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

You can also refer to this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html